# PySide: How can I pass additional arguments to a slot connected to QProcess finished signal in addition to the exitCode it sends?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

QProcess's finished signal returns exitCode as a parameter. I am trying to create a lambda function to connect this signal, but I can't figure out how to send additional arguments to it:

```
    b=2
    process.finished.connect(lambda a=a:self.onFinish(a))

def onFinish(self,exitCode,a):
   #do something
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: onFinish() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I was hoping that the exitStatus would automatically get propagated to the lambda function, but it doesn't seem to.

The above code does not seem to work.

Comment: change to `process.finished.connect(lambda exitCode, exitStatus,  a=a : self.onFinish(exitCode, a))`

Comment: Weird, I though I tried that and it didn't work. But It works now so thanks!

Comment: You have to read in more detail the answer to the duplicate question: param1 = exitCode and param2 = exitStatus and arg1 is a